# Using Sequence and widget handle with Many2many field Odoo15

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-15

I have an issue. I have added a many2many field to the product.template model. I have regular 'sequence' field. The many2many field has tree/list view I can manage the drag / movable option of the many2many table by using the following:

```
<field name="tag_ids">
 <tree create="false" delete="false">
 <field name="sequence" widget="handle"/>
 <field name="name"/>
</tree>
</field>
```

The problem is the tag names will be shown on the website. So, there can be 20 tags to 100 tags for each product, and the same tag could belong to many other products. and it is needed to define which tag should be shown first and which later for each product. So from the backend, the order of the tags needs to be defined by adding/removing using the widget handle of sequence. How to keep the order of the tags added in each product record the way I added them, knowing that many tags will be shared among products?

Comment: Have you tried One2Many field instead?

Comment: No, it has to be Many2many field

Comment: Hi @ElhagagAbdalla, first make sure you defined the _order slot of your python class.
It will make sure the tags, when searched, are in the order of sequences ( `_order = 'sequence ASC'` or `_order = 'sequence DESC'`.

Now, be aware that if you use your sequence at different places, it will be changed and only the last change will be taken into account.
The idea of @holydragon using One2many field is more viable but I understand your need (no duplicate tags - I suppose).

Comment: Hi @PierreLocus all the stuff you mentioned is already done, my problem is the tags will be duplicated. So I need a way to keep the sequence separated for each tag in the product without affecting its sequence in other products

Comment: Right @ElhagagAbdalla, I don't think you'll be able to achieve this :) unfortunately as stated in my last message, it will take the last sequence only, it's just a Integer field, there is no magic there :/ ...